# how to resolve daemon configuration error in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, daemon

I installed new java and android studio in windows 7 64 bit.. and when i created new project this error is occuring.. 
I tried gradle properties (org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m)
I also tried by deleting .gradle folder but still getting the same error
Kindly help me in resolving this issue..
this is error 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comment this line

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
```

in your `gradle.properties` file.

Finally clean your build and run again.